# How to add server side business logic for a AWS amplify GraphQL API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-serverless

Following schema can be found similar on [AWS docs > Designing your schema](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/designing-your-schema.html). What I couldn't find until now is an example where only ToDo's with the Status `PUBLISHED` are exposed by the GraphQL API.

```js
type Todo {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  description: String
  status: TodoStatus
}

enum TodoStatus {
  DRAFT
  PUBLISHED
  DELETED
}
```

All AWS Amplify directives are described [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives), also `@auth` where authorization rules for the ToDo model can be defined but this is not what I am looking for. Furthermore I think that [functions](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function) won't help either in my case, or am I wrong?

Any Idea how I can make ToDo items with Status `DRAFT` and `DELETED` **not accessible via GraphAPI (serverside, not in the frontend via queries)**?

Respectively is this possible and as easy as it would be with tools like [Django and Django Graphene](https://www.twilio.com/blog/graphql-apis-django-graphene)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the way to go is a **[custom resolver](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/resolvers#add-a-custom-resolver-that-targets-an-aws-lambda-function)**.

**Resolvers are what sit between the API endpoint and the database.** They decide who can access this data, what data are they looking for, and how much data they are getting.

DynamoDB resolvers are written in Velocity Template Language (`*.vtl`), which is a language that many developers are probably not familiar with and unfortunately the AWS documentation does not supply many code examples.

Comment: This is a good question and I'm trying to find the answer myself. But this answer goes against the official GraphQL recommendation of having a separate business logic layer (https://graphql.org/learn/authorization/). Still searching for a single real world Amplify example.